# C++ differences between () and {}

Tags: c++

I am learning `C++`. 
I've seen some people doing this:

```
int a = 2;
```

But also:

```
int b(2);
```

And also:

```
int c{2};
```

What am I supposed to use?
What are the differences between those?

Thanks,
Do'

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612075/how-to-use-c11-uniform-initialization-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612075/how-to-use-c11-uniform-initialization-syntax)

Comment: Also: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403621/why-uniform-initialization-initialization-with-braces-is-recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403621/why-uniform-initialization-initialization-with-braces-is-recommended)

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: "Uniform initialization syntax" with `{}` is not truly uniform due to `std::initializer_list` complications. Advice to prefer `{}` over `()` is quite outdated now, and in the next C++ standard we're getting a "true" uniform initialization syntax with `()`. However I'm not yet sure how that handles the most vexing parse.

Comment: related/dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives

Comment: @NathanOliver the top answer on that question is somewhat outdated as I explained above. It is now dubbed ["*almost* uniform initialization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952301/c17-almost-uniform-initialization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I supposed to use ?

You can use any of them.

> What are the differences between those ?
>
> ```
> int a = 2; // A
> int b(2);  // B
> int c{2};  // C
> ```

A is copy initialisation. B and C are direct initialisation.

C uses a braced-init-list and is therefore direct list initialisation. A and B allow initialising with a narrowing conversion while list initialisation allows only non-narrowing conversion. This is sometimes advantageous, since it can help detect unintentional narrowing which is a source of bugs. In this particular case however, it is safe to assume that 2 is appropriate value for `int`.